# In my assembler program add works as mov

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I am writing a basic program in assembly that calculates the sum of all squares from 1 to n and prints out the result. I am using this online tool to do it http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ (if you will use this tool, it usually thorws execution time exceeded errors. Just run it 2nd or 3rd time and it should work fine).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n=6, sum;

    _asm{
            push eax    //temp
            push ebx    //i
            push ecx    //n
            push edx    //sum
            mov ebx, 1
            mov ecx, n
            mov edx, 0
            inc ecx
    //-------------------------------
            loop:
            mov eax, ebx        // assign temp to i so we could calculate square
            mul ebx             // multiply the temp with i to get the result of square
            add edx, eax        // add the square result to the sum
            inc ebx             // increment i by 1
            cmp ebx, ecx        // check if i < n
            jl loop             // if it's true, go to loop
            mov sum, edx        // at the end make sum be equal to edx (sum variable)
    //-------------------------------
            pop eax
            pop ebx
            pop ecx
            pop edx
   }
    cout << "The sum of squares from 1 to " << n << " is " << sum << endl;
}
```

The problem I get is that the sum will be equal to n^2, so that if we enter 5, it prints 25, input 10 outputs 100.

I think it has to do something with this line:

```
add edx, eax        // add the square result to the sum
```

It acts like mov, which in results makes my sum to be the square of last loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `mul ebx` produces its result in `edx:eax` (and for small numbers the upper half is 0).  If you don't want that, use the more efficient `imul eax, ebx` to only write `eax`.  Next time use a debugger: single-stepping will make it obvious which instruction zeroes `edx`, so you can go look up how it works.

Comment: Thank you, Peter Cordes, you fixed this issue!